# How to send a parameter to getters in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, getter

I have a getter to check the product stock and amount of the cart. So here is my getters.js:

```
export const checkStock = (state, productID) => {
    let stockAvailable = true;
    state.cart.forEach(item => {
        if(item.product.id == productID) {
            if(item.product.attributes.stock <= item.amount){
                stockAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    })
    return stockAvailable;
}
```

So as you see, I am sending `productID` to this function as a parameter. And then in the Product component, I am calling this function and I want to add `productID` to this function but I don't know-how.

```
checkStockAvailability(productId) {
            return this.$store.getters.checkStock;
        },
```

So how do you think I can add `productID` to my getters function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameters in getters by returning a function that returns the results:

```js
export const checkStock = (state) => (productId) => {
    // call the checkStockAvailability here
    let stockAvailable = true;
    state.cart.forEach(item => {
        if(item.product.id == productID) {
            if(item.product.attributes.stock <= item.amount){
                stockAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    })
    return stockAvailable;
}

// then you can use this getter on the component as

const productId = 2;
store.getters.checkStock(productId)
```